# adding an error band on a graph when having errors in both x- and y-direction

Tags: r, data-visualization, error

I have a dataset with x and y values which are both calculated averages from three values and consequently they also have an associated error.

I have about 100 x,y points which I want to plot. Adding both horizontal and vertical error bars is a good method, only there are too many points and it doesn't look nice. In this graph (excel example below) I can see that in some zones the vertical error reaches the furthest and in some zones the horizontal error reaches furthest.

To make a nicer graph I want to use the largest error and make an error area (instead of error bars). But I am quite puzzled by the mathematics and how I should write a script or use a graphical tool to create such a graph.

I would think there should be some kind of solution with a loop going through each x and y value and looking for the min and max for each original xy point, but I couldn't get the maths right to do this.

Is there anybody familiar or sees a solution to this problem, preferably implementable in R.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

If the main objective is to de-clutter your plot, one option is to assign different colors to the x- and y-error bars and removing the crossbars at the ends of the error bars. Using `ggplot` you can accomplish this by setting the `color` aesthetic for each set of error bars individually. Also, use `geom_linerange` to remove the crossbars for the y-error bars. For some reason, the default behavior for `geom_errorbarh` is to not plot crossbars.

```
library(tidyverse)

# simulate some data
df <- data_frame(x = seq(0, 3, length.out = 100)) %>%
  mutate(y = 400 - 25*x^2,
         xerr = .05 + .1*x,
         yerr = .1*y,
         xmin = x - xerr,
         xmax = x + xerr,
         ymin = y - yerr,
         ymax = y + yerr)  

# plot using different colors
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax), color = 'blue') + 
  geom_line(color = 'red')
```

[image: error band using different colored error bars]

Otherwise, if you truly want a band instead of individual error bars, could plot polygons that encompass the greatest extent of the x- and y-error of each point. In `ggplot` this is accomplished by defining a path around each x, y pair. Overplotting will produce the band you're trying to create.

I do have some misgivings about suggesting this, however. Presumably the error bars are some sort of confidence interval on the means of x and y. The corresponding confidence region on the joint distribution of x and y is not the rectangle spanned by the error bars but an ellipse.

```
# calculate path for polygons
mutate(df, group = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
  select(-x,-y, -xerr, -yerr) %>%
  gather(xtype, x, xmin, xmax) %>%
  gather(ytype, y, ymin, ymax) %>% 

  # sort rows so that we get rectangles and not bow-ties
  mutate(order = 
           ifelse(xtype == 'xmin' & ytype == 'ymin', 1,
                  ifelse(xtype == 'xmax' & ytype == 'ymin', 2,
                         ifelse(xtype == 'xmax' & ytype == 'ymax', 3, 4)
                         )
                  )
         ) %>%
  arrange(order) %>%

  # plot
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), fill = 'grey') + 
  geom_line(data = df, color = 'red')
```

[image: error band using geom_polygon]